# Why Parse push.setQuery not working on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I'm trying to send a notification to the owner of a post when another user taps the "favorite" button, but I'm receiving an error:

> Can't set both the query and channel (s) properties.

What can it be? My current code:

```
let query = PFInstallation.query()
if let query = query {
    query.whereKey("installationUser", equalTo: self.job!["owner"]! as! String)
    let push = PFPush()
    push.setChannel("Global")
    push.setMessage("Some cool text here")
    push.setQuery(query)
    push.sendPushInBackground()
}
```

The app crashes whenever I execute the line `push.setQuery(query)`

Comment: I think this is expected behavior. It wouldn't make sense to set a push notification to a channel (which can target many users) and to an installation which would overlap. One is much more specific than the other.

Comment: Thank you @pbush25 o/
I just remove the line push.setChannel("Global") and now everything is fine!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the line push.setChannel("Global")